# Print odd index in same line

Tags: python

I'm trying to complete challenge on HackerRank ( Day 6 : Let's review!) and I only did to print the even numbers on the same line, but I can't print the odd indexes that would be needed to complete the challenge.
This is my code:

```
word_check = input()
    for index, char in enumerate (word_check):
        if (index % 2 == 0):
           print( char ,end ="" )
```

This is the most specific task:
Given a string, S , of length N that is indexed from 0 to N -1  , print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as  space-separated strings on a single line.

Thanks!!!
RavDev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [slice notation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) for indexing the original string:

```
word_check[::2] + " " + word_check[1::2]
```

`[::2]` means "start at the beginning and skip every second element until we reach the end" and `[1::2]` means "start at the second element and skip every second element until we reach the end". Leaving out either start or stop arguments of the slice implies beginning or end of the sequence respectively. Leaving out the step argument implies a step size of 1.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but I resolve with for loop because I'm still beginner on Python

Comment: @RavDev Then it's a good place / moment to start learning about these more high-level concepts that Python offers. They help you write more concise and more performant code. Once you get used to it, it reads very natural. A lot of problems can be solved in Python by avoiding explicit `for` loops and instead using builtin functions or the standard library. This has the advantage that internally these things can run at C speed while an explicit `for` loop will run in the interpreter and thus run slower. Plus often it is more concise and clear.

Comment: Excuse me for disturbing @a_guest again but where can I find these high-level concepts in Python and what are the main ones?

Comment: @RavDev The Python docs are comprehensive but might also be a bit overwhelming to begin with. I suggest "learning by researching" in a sense that whenever you need to solve some problem think of it in an abstract way rather then in terms of implementation details and then (re)search a solution (where Stackoverflow or any search engine is a good starting point). Just like you did with this particular task of extracting even and odd items from a sequence. And now you've learnt a new concept on the way :-) If you research thoroughly you'll eventually find an answer and can learn something new.

Comment: By the way https://realpython.com/ also has some nice tutorials on various topics around the Python landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Slice notation is a better approach, but if you want to use `for loop` and stick to your approach, you can do in this way:

```
even =''
odd=''
for index, char in enumerate (word_check):
    if (index % 2 == 0):
        even += char
    else: odd += char
print (even, odd)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently trying to solve the same problem. To get your answers on the same line, initiate two strings: one for even and one for odd. If the character's index is even, add it to the even string and vice versa. Here is my working code so far:

```
def indexes(word,letter):
    result = list()
    for i,x in enumerate(word):
        if x == letter:
            result.append(i)
    return result

T = int(input())
if T <= 10 and T>= 1:
    for i in range(T):
        evenstring = ""
        oddstring = ""
        lastchar = False
        S = input()
        if len(S) >= 2 and len(S) <= 10000:
                for index, char in enumerate (S):
                    if (index % 2 == 0):
                        evenstring += char
                    else: oddstring += char

                    if len(indexes(S, char)) > 1:
                        evenstring.replace(evenstring[evenstring.rfind(char)], '')
                        oddstring.replace(oddstring[oddstring.rfind(char)], '')
                print(evenstring, oddstring)
```

Your next problem now is trying to remove any reoccurrences of duplicate letters from your final answer (they show up in other test cases)