# If the forloop is executing more than 1 time than the print statement will also be executed more than once right?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, logic

Given a string, S , print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as 2 space-separated strings on a single line

I've written my code as

```
S=input()
string=""
string2=""
list1=[]
list1[:0]=S
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if(i%2==0):
        string=string+list1[i]
    else:
        string2=string2+list1[i]
print(string," ",string2)
```

and it worked. But i found this another solution to that question and i'm not able to understand that how is it working.

```
for i in range(int(input())): 
    
    s = input()
    print(s[::2], s[1::2])
```

Can someone please explain this to me. I mean if the forloop is executing more than 1 time than the print statement will also be executed more than once right? Also the input type is a string like "rank" then how is it going to get convert to an int type

Comment: Are you sure this works for your problem? It gives error.

Comment: Yes. I was solving it in hackerrank and my code was not working but this code worked

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58130371/4983469 should answer your question. The second code loops over an input and there is another input that is taken from inside the forloop. Maybe the first input is to get the number of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like the alternate solution is accepting a number N as the number of test cases before actually printing the even and odd indexed characters for each case `s`.

Answer (score 0):

At first the user types in a number. That is how often the user can input strings.

> The `s[::2]` statement returns every second char in the string.

> The `s[1::2]` statement returns every second char in the string, but
> starts at the second char of the string.